# How to detect "strikethrough" style from xlsx file in R

Tags: python, r, excel, strikethrough

I have to check the data which contain "**strikethrough**" format when importing excel file in R

Do we have any method to detect them ?
Welcome for both R and Python approach

Comment: I don't have time right now to post a proper answer at all, but it looks like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) might be your best bet if you can do it in Python.

Comment: It would be helpful if i can have your example when you have time Jarak ,as i am newbies of python .  Checked there is an approach from other post : if Cell.font.strikethrough == True: print('YES')   --- assuming we have strikethrough in " Cell " . But i am not sure whether its performing a detecting function , and the result turn - 'str' object has no attribute 'font'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### R-solution

the `tidyxl`-package can help you...

example temp.xlsx, with data on A1:A4 of the first sheet. Below is an excel-screenshot:

[image]

```
library(tidyxl)

formats <- xlsx_formats( "temp.xlsx" )
cells <- xlsx_cells( "temp.xlsx" )

strike <- which( formats$local$font$strike )
cells[ cells$local_format_id %in% strike, 2 ]

# A tibble: 2 x 1
#   address
#   <chr>  
# 1 A2     
# 2 A4
```

Comment: Thankyou , Wimpel ,this package is awesome , straightforwardly solve my problem. Find strikethrough out , delete the whole row them.

Comment: couldd't find the pip for 'tidyxl' .  How did you installed

Answer (score 2):

I present below a small sample program that filters out text with strikethrough applied, using the openpyxl package (I tested it on version 2.5.6 with Python 3.7.0).  Sorry it took so long to get back to you.

```
import openpyxl as opx
from openpyxl.styles import Font


def ignore_strikethrough(cell):
    if cell.font.strike:
        return False
    else:
        return True


wb = opx.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
colA = ws['A']
fColA = filter(ignore_strikethrough, colA)
for i in fColA:
    print("Cell {0}{1} has value {2}".format(i.column, i.row, i.value))
    print(i.col_idx)
```

I tested it on a new workbook with the default worksheets, with the letters a,b,c,d,e in the first five rows of column A, where I had applied strikethrough formatting to b and d.  This program filters out the cells in columnA which have had strikethrough applied to the font, and then prints the cell, row and values of the remaining ones.  The col_idx property returns the 1-based numeric column value.

Comment: Is it possible to check and find the strike applied for a single word?

Comment: @VineeshTP I don't know for sure (I'm nowhere close to an expert on openpyxl), but from a quick look at the docs, it didn't look to me like the package provides that level of granularity.  It might be worth the above script on a sample anyway, just in case it detects any use of strikethrough within the given cell.

Comment: @Jark: I could identify the strike only if, cell value is fully striked out. I realized that while reading(wb = opx.load_workbook('test.xlsx')) ,  'openpyxl' losing the cellformats if it contains multiple styles (rich text). Any idea to retain the formats?

Comment: @VineeshTP Don't know sorry.  From looking at the [library's issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues) it appears that this may be out-of-scope for the library, at least partially because there isn't a well-defined approach to recording styling on individual parts of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method below:

'# Assuming the column from 1 - 10 has value : A , the 5th A contains "strikethrough"

```
TEST_wb = load_workbook(filename = 'TEST.xlsx')
TEST_wb_s =  TEST_wb.active

for i in range(1, TEST_wb_s.max_row+1):
    ck_range_A = TEST_wb_s['A'+str(i)] 
    if ck_range_A.font.strikethrough == True:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

But it doesn't tell the location (this case is the row numbers),which is hard for knowing where contains "strikethrough" when there is a lot of result , how can i vectorize the result of statement ?

Comment: Is it possible to find a string contains  strike for a single word?