# Eliminate Excel rows in R based on cells with specified formatting (e.g., strikethrough)?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

How can I eliminate Excel rows in R when a particular kind of formatting characterizes a cell (e.g., strikethrough)?
I am in particular wanting to eliminate rows of which the cell in column 1 has strikethrough formatting ("struckthrough"). Using `dplyr::join()` functions in conjunction with `readxl::read_xlsx()`, I could also work with just a vector of cells in column 1 containing the struckthrough values.

It looks like the `tidyxl` package is the way to go. Applying the answer by @Wimpel to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107584/how-to-detect-strikethrough-style-from-xlsx-file-in-r), about *detecting* the strikethrough style, I have this so far:

```
xlfile <- 'PATH TO .XLSX FILE' 
xlin <- xlsx_cells(xlfile)
formats <- tidyxl::xlsx_formats(xlfile)
cells   <- tidyxl::xlsx_cells(xlfile, sheets = 1)
strike <- which( formats$local$font$strike )
strike_cells <- cells[ cells$local_format_id %in% strike, 2 ]
nostrike_cells <- cells[ !cells$local_format_id %in% strike, 2 ]

xl_new <- anti_join(xlin, strike_cells)
```

However, I do not yet know how to get from there (*screenshot below*) to a data frame sans the excluded cells.
[image: tidyxl dataframe after anti_join, so sans excluded cells]

The `tidyxl` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyxl/vignettes/tidyxl.html) describes the package's helpful avoidance of data frame coercion, but I am having trouble with creating the ultimate data frame.

Perhaps someone has a solution using `tidyxl` or another R package like `openxlsx`?

Answer (score 5):

The following used `tidyxl` and `dplyr` for reading + processing and then `openxlsx` for writing the Excel file.

In short, `tidyxl` functions `xlsx_formats` and `xlsx_cells` are used to identify the cells with strikethrough formatting and then the other rows are captured as a numeric vector with `dplyr::pull()` (object `nostrike_rows_vector`). Then `dplyr::slice()` captures only those rows specified by `nostrike_rows_vector` .

```
library(tidyxl)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
xlfile <- 'PATH TO .XLSX FILE' 
xlin <- xlsx_cells(xlfile)
formats <- xlsx_formats(xlfile)
cells   <- xlsx_cells(xlfile, sheets = 1)
strike <- which( formats$local$font$strike )
strike_cells <- cells[ cells$local_format_id %in% strike, 2 ]
strike_rows <- inner_join(strike_cells, cells) %>%
    distinct(row) 
nostrike_rows_vector <- anti_join(cells, strike_rows) %>%
    distinct(row) %>%
    # Do not consider header row
    # Remember this code only works if the first row is a header row
    dplyr::filter(row != 1) %>%
    # tidyxl xlsx_formats and xlsx_cells functions treat row 1 as header
    mutate(row = row - 1) %>%
    pull(row)
xlout <- xlin %>% 
           slice(nostrike_rows_vector)
write.xlsx(xlout, "cleaned_excel_file.xlsx")
```

**Notes:**

1. This R code assumes the Excel file has a header row (i.e., row 1 specifies column names) that you want to keep.
2. Blank cells appear to also be treated as cells with strikethrough formatting. This was fine for my use case but I suggest spot-checking to ensure desired results.